# Resizing symbol changes its position on the map

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-9.3, symbology

I have character symbol for my point feature class from ESRI AMFM Water - Unicode 117 with offset Y:10,7 and size 36. At that moment it is placed perfectly as it is shown on a first printscreen. However when I change the size it gets shifted. I hope my printscreens represent perfectly what I mean. Do you how to change the way my points are resized?

I work with ESRI 9.3.1.[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have to update your Y offset value.

Comment: True I should however I don't want to that. Why my symbols aren't resizing basing on the buttom of my symbol. That element of my point is it centroid.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since I used ArcGIS 9.3 but I think this advice using a 10.2 screenshot and marker should still apply.

Open the Symbol Property Editor on your symbol and make sure that, like the symbol below, both layers originate on the cross-hairs.

[image]